# Wireguard VPN handshake successful but no traffic/ ping

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I have set up WireGuard VPN on my router (FritzBox) and added the VPN config to my Manjaro Gnome notebook.
My router in the LAN at home is available on 192.168.0.1.

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xxxx
Address = 192.168.0.201/24
DNS = 192.168.0.1
DNS = fritz.box

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
PresharedKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.0/24,0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = xxx.myfritz.net:58130
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

From the WireGuard logs that I found in the kernel, it seems like the handshake was successful.

```bash
sudo dmesg -wT | grep wireguard
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:43:25] wireguard: WireGuard 1.0.0 loaded. See www.wireguard.com for information.
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:43:25] wireguard: Copyright (C) 2015-2019 Jason A. Donenfeld <Jason@zx2c4.com>. All Rights Reserved.
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:29] wireguard: wg_config: Interface created
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:29] wireguard: wg_config: Peer 5 created
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:29] wireguard: wg_config: Sending keepalive packet to peer 5 ((einval))
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:29] wireguard: wg_config: Sending handshake initiation to peer 5 ((einval))
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:34] wireguard: wg_config: Peer 5 ((einval)) destroyed
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:34] wireguard: wg_config: Peer 6 created
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:34] wireguard: wg_config: Sending keepalive packet to peer 6 (remote-ip:58130)
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:34] wireguard: wg_config: Sending handshake initiation to peer 6 (remote-ip:58130)
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:35] wireguard: wg_config: Receiving handshake response from peer 6 (remote-ip:58130)
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:35] wireguard: wg_config: Keypair 2 created for peer 6
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:35] wireguard: wg_config: Receiving keepalive packet from peer 6 (remote-ip:58130)
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:45] wireguard: wg_config: Receiving keepalive packet from peer 6 (remote-ip:58130)
[Mo, 16. Okt 2023, 00:55:56] wireguard: wg_config: Receiving keepalive packet from peer 6 (remote-ip:58130)
```

But still I cannot access the page of my router or any other service in my LAN at home or even do a ping.
The request just time-out.

I've read that I need to check if there is a route to my router at 192.168.0.1 over the WireGuard interface, but to me, it seems like there is one:

```bash
ip route get 192.168.0.1                                         ✔ 
192.168.0.1 dev wg_config src 192.168.0.201 uid 1000 
    cache
```

Any idea what is going on there? Are there any additional logs / info that I can provide?
I know that this config works on a different PC.

Edit: Here is the output of `sudo wg show` while the VPN is active, but i think it doesn't show anything surprising.

```bash
sudo wg show                                                     ✔ 
interface: wg_config
  public key: xxxx
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820
  fwmark: 0xcaed

peer: xxxx
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: public-ip:58130
  allowed ips: 192.168.0.0/24, 0.0.0.0/0
  latest handshake: 2 seconds ago
  transfer: 124 B received, 19.25 KiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds
```

Edit #2: Additional information

```bash
ip -br link; ip -br addr; ip route; ip rule                                                                        ✔ 
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
wlp0s20f3        UP             34:7d:f6:8e:6e:a3 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
virbr0           DOWN           52:54:00:1b:79:e3 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-b70272889e99  DOWN           02:42:cf:67:52:3b <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
docker0          DOWN           02:42:cf:d9:9e:e6 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
wg_config        UNKNOWN        <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> 
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
wlp0s20f3        UP             192.168.0.62/24 fe80::a493:410e:53d0:9d48/64 
virbr0           DOWN           192.168.122.1/24 
br-b70272889e99  DOWN           172.26.1.1/24 
docker0          DOWN           172.26.0.1/24 
wg_config        UNKNOWN        192.168.0.201/24 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.62 metric 600 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wg_config proto static metric 20050 
172.26.0.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1 linkdown 
172.26.1.0/24 dev br-b70272889e99 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.1.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wg_config proto static scope link metric 50 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wg_config proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.201 metric 50 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.62 metric 600 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
0:  from all lookup local
30960:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
30961:  not from all fwmark 0xcaed lookup 51949
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

```bash
ip route show table 0                                                                                              ✔ 
default dev wg_config table 51949 proto static scope link metric 20050 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.62 metric 600 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wg_config proto static metric 20050 
172.26.0.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1 linkdown 
172.26.1.0/24 dev br-b70272889e99 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.1.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wg_config proto static scope link metric 50 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wg_config proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.201 metric 50 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.62 metric 600 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 172.26.0.1 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope host src 172.26.0.1 
broadcast 172.26.0.255 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1 linkdown 
local 172.26.1.1 dev br-b70272889e99 table local proto kernel scope host src 172.26.1.1 
broadcast 172.26.1.255 dev br-b70272889e99 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.26.1.1 linkdown 
local 192.168.0.62 dev wlp0s20f3 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.0.62 
local 192.168.0.201 dev wg_config table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.0.201 
broadcast 192.168.0.255 dev wlp0s20f3 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.62 
broadcast 192.168.0.255 dev wg_config table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.201 
local 192.168.122.1 dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.122.1 
broadcast 192.168.122.255 dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
fe80::/64 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
local ::1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::a493:410e:53d0:9d48 dev wlp0s20f3 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev wlp0s20f3 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

Edit #4: After changing the network configuration of the remote network to 192.168.1.0/24 the new output looks like this:

```bash
default dev wg_config table 51949 proto static scope link metric 20050 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.58 metric 600 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wg_config proto static metric 20050 
172.26.0.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1 linkdown 
172.26.1.0/24 dev br-b70272889e99 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.1.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wg_config proto static scope link metric 50 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wg_config proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.201 metric 50 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.58 metric 600 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 172.26.0.1 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope host src 172.26.0.1 
broadcast 172.26.0.255 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1 linkdown 
local 172.26.1.1 dev br-b70272889e99 table local proto kernel scope host src 172.26.1.1 
broadcast 172.26.1.255 dev br-b70272889e99 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.26.1.1 linkdown 
local 192.168.0.201 dev wg_config table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.0.201 
broadcast 192.168.0.255 dev wg_config table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.201 
local 192.168.1.58 dev wlp0s20f3 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.1.58 
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev wlp0s20f3 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.58 
local 192.168.122.1 dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.122.1 
broadcast 192.168.122.255 dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
fe80::/64 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
local ::1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::a493:410e:53d0:9d48 dev wlp0s20f3 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev wlp0s20f3 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is really a good topic for Unix/ Linux or more one for Superuser or Stackoverflow. Feel free to give me feedback.

Comment: `sudo nft list ruleset` returned nothing BTW

Answer (score 2):

Is this the WireGuard config that the FritzBox generated for you via this process?:

https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7590/3685_Setting-up-a-WireGuard-VPN-to-the-FRITZ-Box-on-the-computer/

If so, you won't be able to test it when your notebook is using the FritzBox WiFi -- you have to test it on a different network. Your home network uses the `192.168.0.0/24` subnet, so you can't get your Internet access from the same (or another) `192.168.0.0/24` network and use your FritzBox WireGuard config at the same time.

---

Edit: If after you made the change to the network from which you're testing, and you've tried again to ping the FritzBox itself through the WireGuard tunnel (eg `ping 192.168.0.1`) and other devices on the FritzBox network with no response, do you still see similar output from `wg show` as before, indicating that handshakes have succeeded and some data has been sent through the tunnel to the FritzBox -- but virtually no data has been received?:

```
latest handshake: 2 seconds ago
transfer: 124 B received, 19.25 KiB sent
```

If handshakes are succeeding, that means that UDP packets to/from the WireGuard listen ports are making it back and forth between the notebook and the FritzBox -- which rules out firewall/routing or other network problems on the public network connection between the notebook and the FritzBox (or are at least not the immediate problem); and it also means the WireGuard keys are correct.

And if you see much more data sent through the WireGuard tunnel to the FritzBox than is received (the 124 bytes received initially were just the result of the handshake, and in the absence of any other traffic you should see the byte count for both sent & received climb by ~100 bytes every 25 seconds due to the PersistentKeepalive setting), that strongly suggests there is some firewall or routing configuration on the FritzBox itself that is blocking tunneled packets from either being received or replied to.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is much you can do about it on a FritzBox, but you may want to check the various admin UI pages to see if there are any settings related to its firewall/routing that you can adjust; or to see if perhaps the WireGuard address assigned to your notebook (`192.168.0.201`) is being used by some other host or is reserved for some other purpose on the FritzBox's network.

Comment: Correct, I get the config from the FritzBox. After the first comments, I already suspected the identical subnets to be a problem, and luckily I was able to change the network configuration of the remote network to 192.168.1.0/24. But still the problem stays the same. I will add the new output of `ip route` to the original thread.

Comment: Some ideas: 1. Did you regenerate the wg config after the subnet change? 2. Does a tcpdump reveal packet flow? 3. Is there a firewall active?

Comment: Can you explain to me how to regenerate the WireGuard configuration? Did I have to change anything in the config itself?

Comment: I tried to do the tcpdump on my wireless interface and indeed it shows some packages going to my WireGuard endpoint like `15:11:54.309923 IP local-ip.51820 > remote-ip.58130: UDP, length 160`. Not sure what this means tho

Comment: And no I don't think that I have a firewall running. `sudo ufw status` returns me `Status: inactive`

Comment: You mentioned in your question that "I know that this config works on a different PC" -- are you using the _exact_ same config on your notebook and the different PC at the same time? If so, generate a new, separate config for your notebook (which should have different PrivateKey, Address, and PresharedKey values).

Comment: No I'm not using the same configuration at the same time. I expected this to be blocked by the WireGuard server

Comment: Edited my answer with some further suggestions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation of what could go wrong. Really appreciating that! I will try to get access to the FritzBox and see if I can find any sensible information there.

Comment: Took a while, but the FritzBox interface shows no signs of a successful connection, even tho the handshake was successful. I am really confused what is going on there. Maybe I need to contact the FritzBox support...